# How to display a list of network shares shared by a Windows computer

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a Windows 2008 server with various software packages installed on it.

I want to know what network shares my server is sharing (and I want to know that from within the server, not by trying to access the shares from another computer).

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to see all shared folder list in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/414798/is-it-possible-to-see-all-shared-folder-list-in-windows)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Start -> Run -> compmgmt.msc -> OK.

Computer Management (Local) -> System Tools -> Shared Folders -> Shares.

This will show you all the current shares on the system as well as allow you to control them, change permissions, modify access, etc.

[image]

**UPDATE:** PowerShell offers another way to quickly get all SMB shares on localhost for Windows 7/Server 2012 and later hosts:

```
PS D:\> get-smbshare

Name   ScopeName Path       Description
----   --------- ----       -----------
ADMIN$ *         C:\WINDOWS Remote Admin
C$     *         C:\        Default share
D$     *         D:\        Default share
E$     *         E:\        Default share
IPC$   *                    Remote IPC
```

Comment: Also shows opened shared by which users.

Comment: On Windows Server, it seems to be under Roles | File Services | Share and Storage Management (verified on 2008R2 only)

Answer (score 22):

From a command prompt, enter the command:

```
net share
```

This will show all shares on the system, including hidden.

Answer (score 15):

From the Command Prompt you can type:

```
net view \\servername /all
```

This should show you all shares on that server even if they are hidden shares.

Comment: Hey dude, THANK YOU!!

I was desperately searching for a mechanism for getting list of connected machines and the shares they exported.

I wish I found this little comment a week ago.

Answer (score 7):

A bit simpler than the accepted answer is direct call to the Shared Folders console: `Start > Run > fsmgmt.msc`

Screenshot of the Shared Folders console

[image]

Answer (score 2):

start > run

```
\\127.0.0.1
```

will do the trick

PLEASE NOTE THIS WILL NOT SHOW HIDDEN SHARES.

Comment: Actually, that does not do the trick. Hidden shares (ADMIN$ C$ IPC$ print$, etc.) are not shown.

Comment: true comment updated answer to reflect this