# Is it possible to see all shared folder list in windows?

Tags: windows-7, shared-folders

We have LAN connected different OS installed systems. If I want to see all shared folder list in windows 7 and its access level whether read or read and write, how and where can I see? Is there any option to stop all shared folders with a single click?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

### To view a list of all shared folders

- Click the Windows button
- Right-click Computer and choose Manage (requires administrative priveleges)
- Traverse to Computer Management > System Tools > Shared Folders > Shares

**Note:** in Windows 8 and 10 the *Computer Management* is easy accessible through the `Windows key + x` shortcut, as a part of the *Power User Menu*

### To disable file sharing

- Click the Windows Logo button.
- Type file sharing in the search results window, and then touch Enter.
- Under "File and Printer Sharing", check to be sure that Turn off file and printer sharing is selected.
- Under "Public Folder Sharing", check to be sure that Turn off public folder sharing is selected.
- Click Save Changes.

Comment: Quicker (and in almost every Windows version the same) is to use the run dialog and enter **compmgmt.msc**. And then continue as described.

Comment: thx was perfect solution :)

Answer (score 33):

## Command Line Way

### List All Shares

```
net share
```

### Stop Sharing a Folder

```
net share sharename /delete
```

### Stop Sharing All Folders

Write a script, and double-click it!

The following script will stop sharing `sharename` and `Share Name 2`. Replace these with your own share names. Save as `stopsharing.bat`.

```
@echo off
net share sharename /delete
net share "Share Name 2" /delete
pause
```

Note how share names with spaces in them must be enclosed by quotes.

### Further Information

```
net share /?
```

Learn about more features including how to add shares from the command line.

Comment: I much prefer the CLI over a GUI!

Comment: That's cool thx :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Network Scanner](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/). Tiny portable software, just input the range of ips you want to see.

> **SoftPerfect Network Scanner** is a free multi-threaded IP, NetBIOS and
>   SNMP scanner with a modern interface and many advanced features. It is
>   intended for both system administrators and general users interested
>   in computer security. The program pings computers, scans for listening
>   TCP/UDP ports and displays which types of resources are shared on the
>   network (including system and hidden).
>
> In addition, it allows you to mount shared folders as network drives,
>   browse them using Windows Explorer, filter the results list and more.
>   SoftPerfect Network Scanner can also check for a user-defined port and
>   report back if one is open. It can also resolve host names and
>   auto-detect your local and external IP range. It supports remote
>   shutdown and Wake-On-LAN.